# Passing generic Type from parent class to state class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I want to create some widget to wrap a ListViewer and also make it generic so that it can be used for many types of data. But I could not be able to pass the Type from the parent class(GenericList) to extending child state class(_GenericListState). Can anybody explain me how can I pass types to child so that I can use that type and access its Provider.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class GenericList<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final T providerType;

  const GenericList({Key? key, required this.providerType}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GenericList> createState() => _GenericListState();
}

class _GenericListState extends State<GenericList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list = Provider.of<T>(context);
    final items = list.map;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          onTap: () => index,
          title: Text(items[items.keys.elementAt(index)]!.name),
          trailing: Text(
            items[items.keys.elementAt(index)]!.totalSpending.toString(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

defining this way solved my problem but I did not understand why it works. Can somebody explain it to me?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class GenericList<T> extends StatefulWidget {

  const GenericList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GenericList<T>> createState() => _GenericListState<T>();
}

class _GenericListState<T> extends State<GenericList<T>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list = Provider.of<T>(context);
    final items = list.map;
    ....
  }
}
```